# Magento 2 secure URL

Tags: magento2, url, https, geturl

I am trying to get a secure url like this:

```
$this->storeManager->getStore()->getUrl('someurl', ['_secure' => 'true']);
```

I still get an insecure url with `http://...`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty `_secure` only works if the URL natively supports HTTPS.

In case it does not (which seems to be your case as your code is totally valid) you can force it using `_forced_secure`:

```
$this->storeManager->getStore()->getUrl('someurl', ['_secure' => true, '_forced_secure' => true]);
```

Also you were casting `true` to a string `'true'` I'm not sure if it's the reason but I changed that in the code I posted.